# System.IdentityModel v4.0 could not found

Tags: asp.net, .net

Am having an error when hosting a website on a server windows 2016 having iis 10. When i host the website am getting system.IdentityModel v4.0 could not found..

The target framework is v4.6 and have a reference of system.identitymodel v4.0 dll.

I have given access to iis user and network service also but still same error..

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance